# Binding redirect for non-strongly named assembly in .NET 4.5.1?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, assembly-binding-redirect

So I'm banging my head against binding redirects in .NET 4.5.1

Is there any trick to allow binding redirect for an assembly that isn’t strongly named ?

My service has a dependency on some ancient package which depends on ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=3.9.43.0  and the PublicKeyToken=null so it’s not strongly named

Now I need to bring in ServiceStack.Redis 5.7.0 which depends on ServiceStack.Interfaces.5.7.0

I can’t use binding redirect because when PublicKeyToken=null it doesn't work
are there more tricks someone knows ?

Are there other things I can do to work around this issue ?

I tried looking at what it will take to upgrade that ancient package and it's massive amount of sensitive code that I'd rather not touch if possible.

Comment: the issue is runtime-only?

Comment: Yeah at runtime it complains with: Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=3.9.43.0

Comment: Because I'm including 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.7.0.0 and the binding redirect doesn't work so that other library that depends on version 3.9.43.0 still wants version 3.9.43.0

Comment: I am not a friend of the GAC, but is it an option installing the two versions in it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I thought about doing that, but wasn't sure how to pull that off, since I have to include both DLLs with the same name. Only way I know of how I could include both DLLs if I could again use binding redirects but as that's my main issue binding redirects don't work. It's like trying to google why the internet is down.

Comment: including is shown here e.g.: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2005/11/30/c-2-0-using-different-versions-of-the-same-dll-in-one-application/